# In Jquery how do I change a css style or switch a class for the label of a radiobutton when that radiobutton is checked?

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of radiobuttons in a group and each radio button has its own label:

```
<label>
<input type="radio" class="lstradio" name="photonum" value="4" id="photonum_1" />
4</label>
```

I also have the css for these labels that work with the hover:

```
label {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;

}
label:hover {
background-color: #FF6; 
}
```

My question: How do I switch the css style or class of the label when my radio button input is checked, using jQuery?

Here is the scenario:

In each fieldset there are a number of radio buttons, idea is to change the css style ONLY for the label of the radio button that is checked in each of these fieldsets...

Perhaps I need to fiddle with the blur() function?

Here is the sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/ykK2s/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do it in `label` on `click()`.

```
$('label').click(function(){
    $('label').removeClass('checked');
    $(this).addClass('checked');
});
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Eunpt/

**EDIT:** The `<span>`s complicate a little bit the thing but this will work:

```
$('label').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('fieldset').find('label').removeClass('radiochecked');
    $(this).addClass('radiochecked');
});
```

Look http://jsfiddle.net/ykK2s/4/

Comment: okay, I tried this way, but my main problem now is that I have a dynamic number of radio buttons in a radio group in a fieldset.  i.e. each fieldset contains a radio group, therefore for each radio button group, only one radio button is selected...so basically for each radio group, the css class change should (1) addClass the 'checked' class for the radio button that is checked (2) removeClass the 'checked' class for all radio buttons IN THAT GROUP AND FIELDSET...any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post example at jsFiddle?

Comment: Note: the jsFiddle code is generated from a php script...you can see that for each fieldset, if another radio button is clicked, it retains the css class...I am trying to get only the checked radio button in each fieldset to have its parent label style changed...

http://jsfiddle.net/ykK2s/2/

Comment: Por cierto, muchisimas gracias por la ayuda maestro!

Comment: Perfecto! That was great! Thanks for helping out a newbie to jQuery! Saludos coridales!

Answer (score 2):

```
<label for="photonum">
    <input type="radio" class="lstradio" name="photonum"
           value="4" id="photonum_1" />
4</label>


<script>
    $('input.lstradio').change(function(){
        var that = $(this);

        if(that.attr('checked')) {
            var selector = 'label[for="' + that.attr('name') + '"]';

            $(selector).addClass('someclass');
        }
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DN4Nu/1/

Comment: Here is the scenario:

In each fieldset there are a number of radio buttons, idea is to change the css style ONLY for the label of the radio button that is checked in each of these fieldsets... 

Perhaps I need to fiddle with the blur() function? 

Here is the sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/ykK2s/2/

Answer (score 1):

If all the radios are wrapped with a label as in your example then this should work:

```
$('input.lstradio').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().class('myclass');
});
```

Comment: Here is the scenario:

In each fieldset there are a number of radio buttons, idea is to change the css style ONLY for the label of the radio button that is checked in each of these fieldsets... 

Perhaps I need to fiddle with the blur() function? 

Here is the sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/ykK2s/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($('#photonum_1').attr('checked') === true) { 
    $("label").toggleClass('oldClass newClass');
}
```

Comment: question did not asked for a event handler

Comment: `How do I switch the css style or class of the label when my radio button input is checked?` Your code only checks on page load, if the user checks the button afterwards nothing will happen.

Comment: the question did not asked what should trigger the event

Comment: Here is the scenario:

In each fieldset there are a number of radio buttons, idea is to change the css style ONLY for the label of the radio button that is checked in each of these fieldsets... 

Perhaps I need to fiddle with the blur() function? 

Here is the sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/ykK2s/2/